# Emacs indentation in lisp mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, auto-indent

When i use emacs' lisp indentation, the closing brackets are moved right leaving bigger space infront than necessary. this is how code looks like,
And also, in my code in 2nd line, it leaves 2 characters, in 3rd line, it leaves 4 characters... in some places, it is backward indented.....

note: please don't try to decrypt the code, just see how bad the indentation looks like....

```
(defun tern-req (port doc c)
  (let* 
      (
       (url-mime-charset-string nil) ; Suppress huge, useless header
       (url-request-method "POST"
               )
       (deactivate-mark nil
            ) ; Prevents json-encode from interfering with shift-selection-mode
       (url-request-data 
    (json-encode doc
             )
             )
       (url-show-status nil)
       (url (
         url-parse-make-urlobj "http" nil nil tern-server port "/" nil nil nil
                   )
        )
       )
    (url-http url #'tern-req-finished 
          (list c)
          )
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lisp code formatting wars are virtually nonexistent because Emacs is the accepted standard. You should leave the closing parens on the same line, though. A space before a closing paren indicates it's for a bigger block which started on a previous line.

```
(defun tern-req (port doc c)
  (let* ((url-mime-charset-string nil) ; Suppress huge, useless header
         (url-request-method "POST")
         ;; Prevent json-encode from interfering with shift-selection-mode
         (deactivate-mark nil)
         (url-request-data
          (json-encode doc))
         (url-show-status nil)
         (url
          (url-parse-make-urlobj "http" nil nil tern-server port "/" nil nil nil)) )
    (url-http url #'tern-req-finished
              (list c)) ))
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for the space-before-close-paren thing?
I've never heard about it before.

Comment: but why does line 3 take 4 spaces whereas line 2 takes only 2 spaces?

Comment: space-before-close-paren is very useful because my forward-sexp was moving the cursor to the next closing bracket, which prompted me to move closing brackets to next line... now, this solution is cleaner.

Comment: @abo-abo: I'm not sure where I picked that up. I did a bit of googling and found nothing. If it's not somewhere in the official Emacs doco then I'll guess maybe I picked it up from Bob Glickstein's book (the O'Reilly giraffe book; *Writing Emacs Extensions* IIRC)

Comment: Wow, that's an ancient book. I was interested because I maintain an
Elisp code formatter which would eliminate the space in the above
situation.

Comment: FWIW, IMHO, there is no need for, and conventionally/typically no use of, such space before *either* closing or opening parens. The only reasonable exception might be to occasionally put the closing paren after a multiple-line list of sexps on a new line, to make it easier to insert another list member at the end of the list - e.g., in code that you expect to change in that way.

Comment: Reformatted slightly, I was sloppy (on a mobile) yesterday.  There is no discrepancy between lines 2 and 3 any longer.